# How do I create openGL context for opentk in dotnetcore c#

Tags: c#, .net-core, glfw, opentk, opengl-4

I'm using opentk to write my graphics console application in C# .Net Core. I inherited the `GameWindow` class as such:

```
class OpenGLWindow:GameWindow
{
    public OpenGLWindow(GameWindowSettings gws, NativeWindowSettings nws):base(gws, nws)
    {
            
    }
    //other overloaded methods here
}
```

and I created the window in main method as such:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");

NativeWindowSettings settings = NativeWindowSettings.Default;
settings.Title = "Befiker";
            
settings.APIVersion = new Version(4, 6);

GameWindowSettings gws = new GameWindowSettings();
            
gws.RenderFrequency = 60.0;
using(var win = new OpenGLWindow(gws, settings))
{
    win.Run();
}
            
Console.ReadKey();
```

The window is created, but I noticed it's not clearing the buffer bit. I'm sure this is because I have not created an opengl context. `NativeWindowSettings` class takes a `SharedContext` which is of type IGLFWGraphics context. Here's where I'm stuck. I have used glfw and opengl 4.6 on c++ and window creation handles context creation. So I dont know how to create the context. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I made a mistake here. I forgot to include two functions. one is swapbuffer(). And the
other is makecurrent(). After including this all opengl functions worked properly.
This means that GameWindow class creates an opengl context by itself. Im still not clear on what the nativewindowsettings class object.sharedcontext is for.